# An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error when I try to do action type of WHEN MATCHED more than once. I have read a few answers and articles on why this happens and MSDN doesn't allow WHEN MATCHED unless its a delete or update with the statement.

However, I fail to find answers for my problem. Could someone please guide me on what I can do here.

I have a merge statement with two WHEN MATCHED and Update conditions and that is what I need. Any ideas of how I can better code this?

```
MERGE [Digibill].[MertleUsedLinkys] AS [Target]
USING [Staging].[MertleUsedLinkys] AS [Source]
ON [Source].[LinkyCode] = [Target].[LinkyCode]
WHEN MATCHED  AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]) > [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]
THEN
 UPDATE SET [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] = [LinkyPiTRunDateUTC],
            [Target].[LinkyQty] = [Source].[LinkyQty]


WHEN MATCHED AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]) <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]
THEN 
UPDATE SET 
            [Target].[LinkyCode] = [Source].[LinkyCode],
            [Target].[ServiceKey] = [Source].[ServiceKey],
            [Target].[CustName] = [Source].[CustName],
            [Target].[SupplyRegion] = [Source].[SupplyRegion],
            [Target].[ServiceStatus] = [Source].[ServiceStatus],
            [Target].[NS_ExtID] = [Source].[NS_ExtID],
            [Target].[PartitionKey] = [Source].[PartitionKey],
            [Target].[BillingMthly_PIT] = [Source].[BillingMthly_PIT],
            [Target].[CurrentBillingPeriod] = [Source].[CurrentBillingPeriod],
            [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] = [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC],
            [Target].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus] = [Source].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus],
            [Target].[LinkyQty] = [Source].[LinkyQty]


         
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (    
        [LinkyCode] ,
    [ServiceKey] ,
    [CustName],
    [SupplyRegion],
    [ServiceStatus],
    [NS_ExtID],
    [PartitionKey],
    [BillingMthly_PIT],
    [CurrentBillingPeriod],
    [LinkyPiTRunDateUTC],
    [CurrBillingPeriodStatus],
    [LinkyQty]
)

 VALUES 
 ([Source].[LinkyCode], [Source].[ServiceKey], [Source].[CustName], [Source].[SupplyRegion], [Source].[ServiceStatus], [Source].[NS_ExtID], [Source].[PartitionKey],
    [Source].[BillingMthly_PIT], [Source].[CurrentBillingPeriod],CONVERT(DATETIME,[Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]),[Source].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus],[Source].[LinkyQty]
)

END;
```

Obviously when I run the code I get the error. Any ideas, leads or workarounds are appreciated.

EDIT:

```
    AS
BEGIN 


MERGE [Digibill].[MertleUsedLinkys] AS [Target]
USING [Staging].[MertleUsedLinkys] AS [Source]
ON [Source].[LinkyCode] = [Target].[LinkyCode]
WHEN MATCHED
THEN 
UPDATE SET
            [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] > [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] 
            ELSE [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]
            END,
            [Target].[LinkyQty] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] > [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyQty] 
            ELSE [Target].[LinkyQty]
            END,
            [Target].[LinkyCode] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyCode]
            ELSE [Target].[LinkyCode] 
            END,
            [Target].[ServiceKey] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[ServiceKey]
            ELSE [Target].[ServiceKey]
            END,
            [Target].[CustName] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[CustName]
            ELSE [Target].[CustName]
            END,
            [Target].[SupplyRegion] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[SupplyRegion]
            ELSE [Target].[SupplyRegion]
            END,
            [Target].[ServiceStatus] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[ServiceStatus]
            ELSE  [Target].[ServiceStatus]
            END,
            [Target].[NS_ExtID] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[NS_ExtID]
            ELSE [Target].[NS_ExtID]
            END,
            [Target].[PartitionKey] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[PartitionKey]
            ELSE [Target].[PartitionKey]
            END,
            [Target].[BillingMthly_PIT] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[BillingMthly_PIT]
            ELSE [Target].[BillingMthly_PIT]
            END,
            [Target].[CurrentBillingPeriod] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[CurrentBillingPeriod]
            ELSE [Target].[CurrentBillingPeriod]
            END,
            --[Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]
            --ELSE [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]
            --END,
            [Target].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus]
            ELSE [Target].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus]
            END
            --[Target].[LinkyQty] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyQty]
            --ELSE [Target].[LinkyQty]
            --END


        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (    
        [LinkyCode] ,
    [ServiceKey] ,
    [CustName],
    [SupplyRegion],
    [ServiceStatus],
    [NS_ExtID],
    [PartitionKey],
    [BillingMthly_PIT],
    [CurrentBillingPeriod],
    [LinkyPiTRunDateUTC],
    [CurrBillingPeriodStatus],
    [LinkyQty]
)

 VALUES 
 ([Source].[LinkyCode], [Source].[ServiceKey], [Source].[CustName], [Source].[SupplyRegion], [Source].[ServiceStatus], [Source].[NS_ExtID], [Source].[PartitionKey],
    [Source].[BillingMthly_PIT], [Source].[CurrentBillingPeriod],[Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC],[Source].[CurrBillingPeriodStatus],[Source].[LinkyQty]
);

END;
```

Comment: Do you actually need `CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC])` i.e. is it a string value you are converting? If so why is it a string in one table but not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions in your update based on the condition you currently have as part of your 'MATCHED' branch. i.e. for the ones you only update in one branch use the case expression to either update it, or leave it the same. Here is an example of one of your columns.

```
[Target].[LinkyCode] =
    CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]) <= [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyCode]
    ELSE [TARGET].[LinkyCode]
    END
```

Comment: I'm writing this but getting an error. Am I missing something? 
 UPDATE SET
        [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] = CASE WHEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] > [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] THEN [Source].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] 
        ELSE [Target].[LinkyPiTRunDateUTC]
  END;
Error: Msg 10713, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).

Comment: Hard to know without knowing the error. You won't want a semi-colon in the middle of your statement?

Comment: Just edited my comment - sorry cannot figure out how to format properly in comments @Dale K

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the complete merge statement. The example I gave us only 1 column, which would replace one column in your existing merge. You need to do the same thing for all columns.

Comment: @newbie The semicolon is a **statement** terminator. It should not go after END (which terminates your case EXPRESSION) unless that is also the last element of the entire MERGE statement.

Comment: after fixing the error above, I now get another error: Msg 264, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MertleUsedLinkys, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
The column name 'LinkyPiTRunDateUTC' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.  I need to use this column twice based on 2 diff conditions @DaleK

Comment: @newbie no you definitely don't use the column twice, you use the case expression to select what you want to set it to based on your conditions - thats the whole point of what I am trying to show you in the example above.

Comment: just had a light bulb moment! Thanks so much :) Issue resolved. You're awesome.

Comment: Hi @Dalek I have posted the improved code up in Edit. Problem now is that the  WHEN NOT MATCHED part is being triggered even when the rows are exactly the same - hence creating duplicates records

Comment: @newbie open a new question - this one is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the logic is either `>` or `<=` then you can just remove one of the conditions

```sql
....
WHEN MATCHED
THEN 
UPDATE SET ....
```

If one of those columns could possibly be null then the logic is not quite the same. You would need to remove it from the source to start with

```sql
...
USING (
    SELECT Source.*
    FROM Staging.MertleUsedLinkys AS Source
    WHERE Source.LinkyPiTRunDateUTC] IS NOT NULL
) AS Source
...
```